# How can I pop up a notification on a specific time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im a new developer with 2-3 months of experience in android app development

I wanted to ask about is there a way to pop up a notification on a specific time or do anything!. I want to play a audio file on a specific time without clicking any button in the app or doing anything. For example : Muslim Pro in that app the prayer audio file is played on a specific time. I want to implement that functionality

Can you please explain to me how to do it?

Comment: You need to use Timer

Comment: try to understand AlarmManager Concept.

Comment: when system time reaches your time then play your audio

Comment: @Basha like a conditional statement example : IF the time is THIS - DO THIS

Comment: @Muhammad Rayyan Siddiqui yes

Comment: @Basha Thank you every much! For answering.

Comment: You can Upvote, if You accept this answer